# Can not create connector in ksqlDB

Tags: ksqldb

I'm using ksqlDB version 5.3.2! When I try execute this query in ksql CLI:

```
CREATE SINK CONNECTOR `hdfs_connector` WITH (
'connector.class'='io.confluent.connect.hdfs3.Hdfs3SinkConnector',
'tasks.max'='1',
'topics'='CUSTOMERS_CITY_2',
'hdfs.url'='hdfs://192.168.2.114:8020/tmp',
'flush.size'='3',
'key.converter'='org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter',
'value.converter'='io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter',
'value.converter.schema.registry.url'='http://192.168.2.113:8081',
'confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers'='192.168.2.113:9092',
'confluent.topic.replication.factor'='1');
```

I get an error:

```
Caused by: line 1:8: no viable alternative at input 'CREATE SINK'
Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.NoViableAltException
```

I don't know my current ksql supports CREATE SOURCE | SINK CONNECTOR feature or not! How can i create source/sink connector to integrate with Kafka Connect? Thanks in advance!
For more information: https://ksqldb.io/examples.html#integrating-with-external-data-sources-and-sinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CREATE … CONNECTOR` was added in ksqlDB 0.6, and will be part of Confluent Platform / KSQL 5.4.

Confluent Platform 5.4 will be released soon, or you can grab ksqlDB 0.6 as a Docker image as shown [in the quickstart](https://ksqldb.io/quickstart.html).